# ionic click delays on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a simple project which has a button and an image. The image shows when pressing the button. But the image shows with delay about 1000ms.
On the browser, there aren't any problems.

and these are the codes

```
<span (click)="getImage()">Click it!</span>

<img src="assets/{{img}}" *ngIf="img" alt="">

  img = "";
  getImage(){
    this.img = "aa.jpg";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove this delay, you can add the `tappable` attribute to your element.

```
<div tappable (click)="doClick()">I am clickable!</div>
```

Source: [Click Delays](https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/#click-delays)

> In general, we recommend only adding (click) events to elements that
>   are normally clickable. This includes  and  elements. This
>   improves accessibility as a screen reader will be able to tell that
>   the element is clickable.
>
> However, you may need to add a (click) event to an element that is not
>   normally clickable. When you do this you may experience a 300ms delay
>   from the time you click the element to the event firing.

Comment: unfortunately, nothing changed.